# NLog in ASP .NET MVC Application with Microsoft Identitiy Platform shows auth:Cookies: in user name field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog, microsoft-identity-platform

We use NLog in our ASP .NET MVC Web Application .NET Framework 4.7.2. Application uses Microsoft Identitiy Platform for user authentication.

We use ${identity} for mapping NLog to database table (a part of Web.config is below in the text).

But ${identity} contains auth:Cookies: instead of real user name.

How can I fix it to real user name?

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<targets>
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
        <connectionStringName>QtContext</connectionStringName>
        <commandText>
            insert into dbo.NLOG (
            Application, Logged, Level, Message, Username, ServerName, Port, Url, Https, ServerAddress, RemoteAddress, Logger, CallSite, Exception
            ) values (
            @Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message, @Username, @ServerName, @Port, @Url, @Https, @ServerAddress, @RemoteAddress, @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception
            );
        </commandText>
        <parameter name="@application" layout="${appsetting:name=AppName:default=Unknown\: set AppName in appSettings}" />
        <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
        <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@username" layout="${identity}" />
        <parameter name="@serverName" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />
        <parameter name="@port" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />
        <parameter name="@url" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}" />
        <parameter name="@https" layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}" />
        <parameter name="@serverAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />
        <parameter name="@remoteAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}" />
        <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
        <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="database" />
</rules>
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace `${identity}` with `${aspnet-user-identity}` ? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetUserIdentity-layout-renderer (Need to enable identity support for the AspNet-application)

Comment: @RolfKristensen, yes we tried using `${aspnet-user-identity}` but then NLog leaves the user empty at all. And that article is about ASP .NET Core, but ew use ASP .NET MVC .NET .NET Framework 4.7.2